# Angular 4 select disabled is not working

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I want to disable `select` in Angular 4.
I wrote code like below but `select` is not disabled.

In the component:

```
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';    

this.eventForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    // ... some codes ...
    'state': [true, Validators.required],
    'stepStrengh': [10, Validators.nullValidator]
});
```

In HTML:

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="state" [value]="true"/> Enable Step
<input type="radio" formControlName="state" [value]="false"/> Disable Step

<select formControlName="stepStrengh" [disabled]="!eventForm.get('timeslots').value">
  <option [ngValue]="10">10 steps</option>
  <option [ngValue]="15">15 steps</option>
</select>
```

When I add `[disabled]="true"` into `option` tag, then that option tag is disabled, but I want to disable the `select` tag itself.

And I tried like this -

```
<select formControlName="stepStrengh" disabled="{{state ? '': 'disabled'}}">
```

But this is also not working, when I change the state variable from `true->false` or `false->true`

Comment: In your code snippet above, state is set to false. When state is set to true, this should be disabled

Comment: state variable will be changed true->false, false-> true !!
but select is not changed. changed the question initial state.

Comment: Okay, can you create a stackblitz to reproduce the error please?

Comment: ok. wait a second. I'll make now

Comment: Lol this is funny, when i deleting `formControlName="stepStrengh"` all works as you do, as expected

Comment: I wondered that is working in stackblitz

Comment: but I'm making the form from FormBuilder

Comment: I've updated the question, I inserted more code to make sense.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

After reading some docs and other stuff I found out that this approach is working for me

```
<select [attr.disabled]="state ? '' : null" formControlName="stepStrengh" >
```

hope it helps.

[Here is a link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v6l2z5?file=app%2Fslider-overview-example.ts)

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. By using `disabled="state"` instead of `[disabled]="state"`, it's simply setting disabled to the string `state` instead of the value of the variable

Comment: if I do like this, when I change the state variable, I want to swap the select to enable/disable.

Comment: i changed, this was just a string my bad

Comment: I tried like this, disabled="{{ state ? '' : 'disabled' }}" but this is not working when I change the state variable.

Comment: thank you. upvoted. but my reputation is too low. upvote number is not changing..:(

Comment: @ShineHan you can mark it as right answer, if it helped. under votes

Answer (score 11):

Your kind of mixing the template driven way with the reactive form way. It's best to choose one approach. In this case in your typescript do: control.disable()

Specifically for your purpose it would be:

this.eventForm.get('stepStrengh').disable();

Note you would set this AFTER your initial form set-up.

Comment: thanks for answering. but can you give me more detail info?

Comment: This is the correct answer !